# Generate po file from excel table

Tags: excel, localization, po

I have a dictionary in an excel file. Is there any software to generate a po file from the Excel sheet for localization, or I have to create a script to generate the po file?
I have found po editors, but I need only to convert the file to po format, instead of editing the existing dictionary.

Comment: it depends on the structure of the excel file. It may be easier to convert it to .csv then make a small script to generate the .po file.